# Menu generation (.net mvc 3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, menu, linq-to-entities

Good day!

I have a task to rewrite site from classic asp to .net mvc. All ok, but I have a trouble with menu generation.

Please, follow redstore.com.ua (yes, it's on-line sex shop :)), on the left side you will find the menu, it's works great. When you click on it, the sub menu will fall down with redirecting to category page.

The database table of menu looks like this:
id - menu id | int 
m_name - menu title | string 
m_rew - url name of item | string
m_parent - the id of parent directory | int 
m_type - type of menu item (1 - the higts level, 2 - middle level (red menu item on site), 3 - submenu level (last level)) | int

I need solution to generate exactly the same functionality menu (what should be in model, controller and view). Can anybody help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 good site which will help you to generate the kind of menus you need.

1. http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx
2. http://forums.asp.net/t/1681889.aspx/1
3. http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/

The menus is just a combination of

.The way you generate the menus is by CSS.
Combine these 3 methods to generate the menus you need.

Comment: I cant use javascript to generate menu, cause it's not approved by SEO company (so, #3 is not approved), #1 is too far from my solution, #2 use xml markup (i need to use data in db)... :(